# WSO2 APIManager 2.0.0 - Set LDAP user as Admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to set admin roles to user from LDAP or any other user.
I added all roles from carbon application (Home > Identity > Users and Roles > List > Role) to new user.
User can login to carbon/publisher/store.
But new user cannot see data in Manage subscriptions and Statistics while admin user can see everything.

Is there something else which need to be setup so that new user have same rights as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation on [publisher permissions that you need to set to view statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Viewing+API+Statistics#ViewingAPIStatistics-APIPublisherstatistics)

The publisher permission also allows managing subscriptions.

So rather than just setting roles only, you also have to set permissions for that role.

Comment: default admin user have rights which I need to add to new user - so I copy roles to new user - didn't work;  than I create new role with all permissions that can be selected and add to new user - didn't work